#  Symfony2  doctrine:schema:drop --force doesn't work

Tags: oracle, symfony, command-line, doctrine, schema

With Symfony 2.0.12 and an Oracle 10g database, I don't understand why my command:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:drop --force
```

doesn't work. It tells me: "Database schema dropped succesfully!" but I have still few tables in my schema.
Does anyone get the same issue ?

I tried with:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:drop --force --full-database
```

and i get:

```
ORA-02264: name already used by an existing constraint
```

And finally after 3 times, my schema is well deleted, but still, I don't understand.

Answer (score 2):

You have cofigure cascade persist because for example, the drop execute:
drop user, and the user have dependencies with other table and throw the error.